# ISO C++ does not include variadic templates

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Good day, guys. I can't really get what's going on with this and where is my mistake? It looks like I am missing small detail, but the code looks okay.

```
#include <pspkernel.h>
#include <pspdebug.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


PSP_MODULE_INFO("CONTROLTEST", 0, 1, 1);
PSP_MAIN_THREAD_ATTR(THREAD_ATTR_USER | THREAD_ATTR_VFPU);

int done = 0;

template<typename... Args>
void Printf(Args... params)
{
    pspDebugScreenPrintf("Test %d\n", params...);
}

int main(void)
{
    pspDebugScreenInit();

    Printf(1);

    while(!done){

    }

    sceKernelExitGame();
    return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting looks like this:

```
main.cpp:12: error: ISO C++ does not include variadic templates
main.cpp:13: error: ISO C++ does not include variadic templates
```

I'm using gcc 4.3.5

Comment: Which compiler? Which version? Which compilation flags? Which architecture?

Comment: Please explain your understanding of what the `...` in your shown code mean (maybe the term "variadic template" can be used in that explanation, but not necessarily, just explain your understanding). Then try to find something which implies that it can be used like that with ISO (i.e. standard) C++.

Comment: Empty infinite loop: `while(!done){}` is UB BTW.

Comment: GCC 4.3 is ***very*** old, and any possible C++11 support it might have (it was the C++11 standard that added template parameter packs) would be incomplete and flawed.

Comment: GCC 10.x will be soon released, why are you still using such an ancient version?

Comment: Thanks guys, everything worked ok. 
I know it's too old, but there was a need to work with an old version.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html), GCC 4.3 added support for variadic templates, but C++0x (which became C++11) was still experimental at that point.

If you really want to use C++11 or newer standards, update to a recent compiler. Specifically, [GCC 4.8.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011 C++ standard, so you should aim at least for that version.